# Use ReplaySubject, but only replay most recent observable item

Tags: angular, rxjs5

I have a ReplaySubject like so:

```
matchCount = new ReplaySubject<number>();
totalCount = new ReplaySubject<number>();
```

I use it like so:

```
  getMatchedEventsCount(){
    return this.dcs.matchCount.asObservable();
  }

  getTotalEventsCount(){
    return this.dcs.totalCount.asObservable();
  }
```

I am just getting the counts - I only need the last (most recent) value from each replay subject, I don't need all the values.

Is there a way to do that?

Comment: I think that means you are looking for a `BehaviorSubject`

Comment: I think you are right - is there some way to set the initial value of the behavior subject asynchronously?

Comment: initialize it with `undefined` or `0`, then set the initial value just like what you're doing with `RelaySubject`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Specify a number of events to replay in the constructor:

```
 new ReplaySubject<number>(1);
```